# Web Api documentation based on type of the content in HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api, documentation

I'm building a WebApi and I want to create documentationfor it.

Most of my methods should return data in format:`{errorCode:200, errorMessage:'msg', data:[item1{}, item2{}, ...]}`.

So I've created a class 'ResponseDTO' for it and added a summary. If in the controller method I return: `return new ResponseDTO(201, "Test", someData);` ASP.NET will create a good standart documentation for me.

But actually I want to return something like this: `return Request.CreateResponse<ResponseDTO>(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);`. In this case ASP.Net creates a documentation about HttpResponseMessage.

Can I make ASP.Net create the documentation about the type which I specify in `CreateResponse<T>`?

Answer (score 1):

I've found exactly what I was looking for: `[ResponseType(typeof(ResponseDTO))]`

Thanks for: [http://www.strathweb.com/](http://www.strathweb.com/2014/01/return-types-action-parameters-and-data-annotations-now-available-in-web-api-2-1-help-page/)